# How to send email reminders on different conditions?

Tags: php, reminders

I have a table called reservations which has columns start_date and end_date.

If date_diff(start_date and end_date) is 30 then I need to send an email on 8,2 and 1 days before end_date. same with the below..

60    – 15,4 & 1
120 and above  – 30, 8, 2 & 1...
any idea how to do this ??

Comment: do the date diff between end date and current date check if it 1 or 2 or 8

Comment: using datediff or float I can check the diff b/w dates. But checking to same thing for different coditions doesnt make sense.

Answer (score 0):

set up cronjob to do this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

write 3 separate sql statements for your query get these to work.

then put these into a mysql_query in php  setting a variable if row count >0

using isset on the variable into email smtp script

set up a cron job to check every morning.

Comment: don't do three queries when you only need one.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *,DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), end_date) as DIFF FROM TABLE WHERE  DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), end_date) in (1,2,8)

Comment: did u read the entire question carefully because i think u miss the 15,4 & 1  in case of 60 and miss the 30, 8, 2 & 1 in case of 120.

Comment: Hello Dagon, your suggestion looks helpful if it is for only one condition. But how about the other conditions ? I need to send an email reminder to all so I'm not sure if I can write separate sql queries for each condition.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you create 2 tables, 1 for the main reservation information and the 2nd one will be for the storing of the send dates (or send reminder dates).

When the saving the record you will then retrieve the difference between the current date and the end_date; if difference will be 30 then you'll have to store send_dates 8,2 and 1 days before the end_date; same with the other conditions you have.

Then create a cron job (that will run daily) to check the 2nd table of the send_dates = current date. Then email if conditions is met.

Hope this is the one you needed

Comment: no need for sql code since you are saving the send dates when the reservation is created. for the cron job you just need to check if the current date is equal to send_date. SELECT tbl1.* FROM tbl2 INNER JOIN tbl1 on tbl2.tbl1_id = tbl1.id WHERE NOW() = tbl2.send_date